# AWSで1分より短い間隔で定期実行する方法

Tags: aws

AWSのマネージドサービスで1分より短い間隔で定期実行する方法はあるでしょうか？
実行内容は、任意のサーバへリクエストを送信する、Lambdaを実行する、などを想定しています。

CloudWatchスケジュールを使えば、1分間隔までは定期実行できます。
しかし、それより短い間隔(毎秒～5秒毎程度を想定)となると実行する手段が分かりません。
何か方法をご存知の方いらっしゃったらご教示ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「AWSのマネージドサービスで」という前提で考えると無さそうです。
Classic Load barancer の Health Check は 5-300秒間隔で HTTP GET リクエストを出せますので それをトリガーに処理を走らせるアイデアを思いつきましたが、厳密な制御はできないと思いますので、素直に秒単位で処理を繰返すスクリプトを開発して デーモンプロセスとして動かすのが良い気がします。